# PHP&SQL select highest score

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm going to select the highest result in my "quiz" table there is 5 type of data: 
**quizid, userid, quizdate, result, topicid**

```
1      JAKE   1/7/2015    60     1  
2      JAKE   1/7/2015    80     1
3      JAKE   1/7/2015    100    2
```

i wanna show each topic and user highest score only once. 

But it only show the first highest score from the user, after user redo the quiz again it wont show the highest score. 

Example: Userid JAKE has done first time quiz have 60  mark at quiz 1, when he redo quiz 1 and get 80 marks it still show 60mark at the Table.

```
Select userid,topicid, MAX(result) as result
FROM quiz GROUP BY userid, topicid
ORDER BY result desc
```

The final result should be show 80 for JAKE at topic 1, but my result was

```
1      JAKE   1/7/2015    60     1  
3      JAKE   1/7/2015    100    2
```

Comment: Executed query after he redoes the quiz ? :p

Comment: Is it definitely in the database? Did the second score even get entered? Could have been an issue with duplicate keys or something, as I imagine you might have tied all the keys together, so you're entering the same UserId and QuizId.

Comment: Well, I don't see an error in the script. Try to filter your quiz table for user JAKE and search the results for the 80 score. I'm sure it won't be there. Doesn't it?

Comment: is that possible topicid duplicate? since user redo the same quiz was using same topicid? @mGuv

Comment: Please do `SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name` for your table and show us the result. It might be some constraint conflict.

Comment: @JakeCube, I can't fully comment on if it is possible or not. I'd need to see the table or the sql used to create it.

Comment: @axxis but how is this possible... i'm still showing the first low result not the highest. :(

Comment: So if you just run a `select * from quiz` do you see all three entries?

Comment: @axxis yes it show 3 entries exactly

Comment: You have flagged this question as both `mysql` and `sql-server`. Did you try this with both servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you should used it like. if you want complete record with max result

```
select * from (Select userid,topicid, result as result
FROM quiz ORDER BY result desc) as t GROUP BY t.userid, t.topicid
```

Comment: above query is working fine and tested please verify your table structure.

Comment: Any idea what will cause this ?

Comment: As per your query is also fine to get the max result. it is weird. i think you needs to verify your table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Try following,

```
Select userid, topicid, result from
(
Select 
    row_number() over (order by userid, topicid, result desc) row_id,
    userid,
    topicid, 
    result
FROM quiz
) t
where row_id = 1
```